# "The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data" error while sending XML string to WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-config, quota

I am working with a .NET, C# application which intends to send a long XML string to a WCF Service method for further operation. When my application tries to send the XML string to WCF Service in runtime, I am getting a error message :

`"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:strProdUserDataXML. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 131, position 57.'. Please see InnerException for more details."`

My application side web.config I have written the "binding" & "endpoint" as:

```
<binding name="EndPointHTTPGenericPortal" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    <security mode="None">
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
    </binding>

    <endpoint address="http://192.168.140.40/WcfGenericPortal_Service/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndPointHTTPGenericPortal" contract="IService1" name="EndPointHTTPGenericPortal" behaviorConfiguration="Graph" />
```

If any body can help me on how to solve this error I will be very much obliged.
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: And what is your server-side web config?

Comment: What is the value for maximum string content length quota on the server side?

Comment: Here is a related Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917061/the-maximum-string-content-length-quota-8192

Comment: Hi Voo & Jocke, thanks for your reply. server-side config is: '<binding name="EndPointHTTPGenericPortal" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
     <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>'

Comment: where is your 'readerQuotas' node?

Comment: Many here are just going with the brute force solution which is to set all of the config values to the maximum of 2 GB (2147483647 bytes), but beware that this may make you vulnerable to DoS attacks, etc. It will work, but there is a reason why the defaults are set so low in comparison.

Comment: In regards to my previous comment - sorry, some are character, array length values, and node depth value - not just byte values in the reader quota config settings.

Comment: I have same issue. except that in my case this happen only on 1 of 4 dev computer which are Dell manufacturer computer which are same exact models. we all use same visual studio and only 1 guys it crashes when we all run the same solution i made. it is on SVN so same exact code. all running ANY CPU.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600057/the-maximum-string-content-length-quota-8192-has-been-exceeded-while-reading-x)

Answer (score 11):

Here is an article on MSDN about [Reader Quotas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx).

It appears that one of the reader quotas on your server side is being exceeded.

Specifically, **maxStringContentLength** is being exceeded. The default value is **8192** characters for **maxStringContentLength** which as described by the error message is being exceeded.

But it may not be the best approach to just bump up all the values to the maximum **2147483647** as some others have suggested.

As written in the MSDN documentation that I linked:

> The complexity constraints provide protection from denial of service
>   (DOS) attacks that attempt to use message complexity to tie up
>   endpoint processing resources. Other complexity constraints include
>   items such as a maximum element depth and a maximum length for string
>   content within the message.

Coupled with the fact that you currently have **Security Mode** set to **None** - you may be setting yourself up for some problems.

Comment: Thanks Derek W for your help. It helped me to solve the issue. I set the maximum value to 2147483647 and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

I got this error and solve by adding this - MaxItemsInObjectGraph property for the service in both the client and the server configuration .

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
```

server side

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Service.Service1Behavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client side

```
<behaviors >
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="endpointbehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and don't forget to apply this behavior to EndPoint  behaviorConfiguration="endpointbehaviour"

Comment: I spend counless hours to troubleshoot the issue. Your solution helped me fix it, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Client Side Binding

```
    <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
messageEncoding="Text">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
<security mode="None">
<transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
realm="" />
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
</binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="KAMServiceDistributor">
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
</behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
<endpoint address="http://localhost:1234/xxxx/Service.svc"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService11"
contract="yourservice namespae" name="AnyName" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service Config File:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>


<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
<dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding <b>maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"</b>>
<readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
</binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="Service">
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService" />
</service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: After filtering all the answers, your answer worked for me..million thanks to you.

Comment: Yes this answer is the most useful among others, because it shows where to place reader quotas settings!

Answer (score 6):

Try to set following things in bindings.

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

It has solved my problem. For more reference find following link http://blogfornet.com/2013/08/the-maximum-string-content-length-quota-8192-has-been-exceeded-while-reading-xml-data/

Comment: That link goes to a holding page now.

Answer (score 5):

Pinaki Karuri,

quotas lengths depend not only on the client's configuration - they also depend on the server's one. Please post your WCF server's web.config so we can shed some light on the problem. There is a probability you already have the quota set there for **8192**, so the quickest way for you would be to find and increase its value.

*Update*

As far as I can see, you are missing 'readerQuotas' node from your server's web.config, so **MaxStringContentLength** has its value set to default (**8192**). Please refer to this link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreaderquotas.maxstringcontentlength.aspx

Comment: Hi Piotr Justyana, Thanks for your reply the server-config is : '<binding name="EndPointHTTPGenericPortal" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"> <security mode="None"/> </binding>'

Comment: Please read my updated answer and my last comment under your question.

Comment: Thanks Piotr Justyana, it worked !!!!! You solved it so easily..Thank you so much your link helped me to solve it so easily while it was becoming a nightmare for me.

Answer (score 1):

Server side

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="200"
                              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                              maxArrayLength="16384"
                              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                              maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client side

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRequestService" allowCookies="true"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" allowCookies="true"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Target Framework for the client is the same as that of the service. I had this issue and tried all of the above fixes but that did not work. Checked properties and checked the Target Framework and changed it.