# WCF: The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded. Readquota not working

Tags: ajax, wcf, web-config

We are having some trouble with the following error:

The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

Now we have found that there are alot of threads talking about editing the web.config, and ofcourse we did but this does not seem to help in our case.

We are doing an ajax POST to our wcf service and we can see that the server receives the data.
Anyone who has an solution?

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BIS.HttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="QNH.Transponder.BIS.BISService"  behaviorConfiguration="BIS.ServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="BIS.EndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BIS.HttpBinding" contract="QNH.Transponder.BIS.IBISService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="BIS.EndpointBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="BIS.ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data" error while sending XML string to WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654892/the-maximum-string-content-length-quota-8192-has-been-exceeded-while-reading)

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the MaxStringContentLength on the **server** and **client** to a larger value as 8192. You have only changed to value at serverside. So have a look at you client configuration to fix your error.